# Can watch from watchkit run videos?

Tags: objective-c, video-streaming, watchkit

Is there any way to run videos on Apple watch using Watchkit within my app? I tried finding any video player, but there was nothing. Thanks!

Comment: There is an app for apple watch named: "Jay", they did integrated a video player in that app!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No - there's currently no way to run video on Apple Watch using Watchkit.

Depending on your desired outcome, you may be interested in the [Animation capabilities](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/WatchHumanInterfaceGuidelines/Animation.html) of WatchKit. By adding a series of images into your Watch App bundle, WatchKit allows you to cycle through them at [up to 120 fps](http://www.happy.watch/blog/2014/12/26/watchkit-animation-frame-rate-tutorial) or slower when fetching images from iPhone.

You could accomplish some pretty amazing results by animating images, although bare in mind image resources need to be kept to a minimum.

I suggest [this tutorial](http://natashatherobot.com/watchkit-animate/) on WatchKit Animation
and [this Swift framework](https://github.com/frosty/Flipbook) for rendering UIViews as image sequences in WatchKit.

Comment: Thanks for your reply..Is there any way in which I can run the video URL in browser within the watch app?